# Add values from each day in mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this image[image]

How do I make a mysql query that adds up each day `gained` points?

I'm using a `while` loop to loop through all of these rows (last 50) and it will show "Gained on Dec 15. 2012 etc etc"

```
DECEMBER 15, 2012
HISTORY ITEM 1 | 500+
HISTORY ITEM 2 | 500+
HISTORY ITEM 3 | 1500+
----PTS GAINED THIS DAY: 2500+

DECEMBER 14, 2012
HISTORY ITEM 1 | 500+
HISTORY ITEM 2 | 500+
----PTS GAINED THIS DAY: 1000+
```

and so on.

Here's what I have so far: `$getIt = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(gained) FROM`history`WHERE`uid`= '$logged[id]' AND`time`> $ts_yesterday ORDER BY`id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

and `$ts_yesterday = strtotime('yesterday', $status['4']);` where `$status` is from `mysql_fetch_array` of the `while` loop... obviiously refrencing the `time` column

Comment: you're trying to add 1 to the gained field for each day?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT SUM(gained), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d") as created_day FROM history GROUP BY created_day

See [here](http://www.cowboycoded.com/2010/04/19/mysql-group-by-day-month-or-year-using-a-timestamp-column/)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Its created_day not creat_day. It basically acts as an alias for DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d").

Comment: The query i have written above is the answer to your question "How do I make a mysql query that adds up each day gained points?". If you want to retrieve the sum of gained each day for each item, then you have to also group by Item_ID. Try this - SELECT SUM(gained), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d") as created_day FROM history GROUP BY created_day, ITEM_ID.
Refer [this](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/sql-group-by-with-multiple-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `select sum(gained) from tablename groupby date`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like sum() and group by are the way to go for you. Another cool feature with MySQL to check out is the ROLL UP modifier for group by. Check it out

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?12,106959,106959
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html (starts talking about the roll up feature about 1/4 down the page.)